# Matplotlib: use TeX only if is available

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I would like to run the following snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
params = {'text.usetex': True}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

but be able to fall back to `'text.usetex' = False` if latex or another requirement (ghostscript comes to mind) is not installed on the machine. What is the most pythonic way to do this?

I was thinking of trying a dummy plot and setting text.usetex to False if an error was raised, but I don't know which error will be raised if latex is not available.

Comment: I think this can lead to all kinds of different errors, also depending on the operating system in use. A generic `try: ... except: ...` would however catch all of those. The drawback is that it slows down the whole code. So an easier method might be to check if you can call `latex -help`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the same functionality. After having a look at [matplotlib's code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/45d38777ed1d321966acc8236cbdad66442dd159/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py#L404-L420), you have a function:

```
import matplotlib
usetex = matplotlib.checkdep_usetex(True)
```

In my case, as LaTeX is not installed, this warning is displayed

```
usetex mode requires TeX.
```

And usetex is set to False.

Comment: This appears to be deprecated: `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The checkdep_usetex function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use a vendored copy of this function instead.`

Answer (score 2):

`matplotlib.checkdep_usetex(True)` will be [depreciated](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9571) in the Matplotlib 3.6 and in future releases. I recommend using this one-liner solution:

```py
from matplotlib import rcParams
import shutil

rcParams['text.usetex']= True if shutil.which('latex') else False
```